# Use CoffeeScript in Rails 3.1 (jQuery) to create a sentence from multi-select options

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I need the text value of selected options in a multiple select returned as a "sentence" - just to join the strings, separated by a comma and a space.

The HTML generated for the select looks like this:

```html
<select id="foo_bazs_attributes_0_bar_ids" name="foo[bazs_attributes][0][bar_ids][]" multiple="multiple" data-validate="true">
  <option value="1">I</option>
  <option value="2">Want</option>
  <option value="3">a</option>
  <option value="4">Sentence</option>
</select>
```

So I need my function to return "I, Want, a, Sentence".

To do this with jQuery, I found the following (at http://calisza.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/6-jquery-snippets-you-can-use-to-manipulate-select-inputs/):

```
var foo = [];
$('#multiple :selected').each(function(i, selected){
 foo[i] = $(selected).text();
});
```

so I wrote the following in my CoffeeScript file:

```
$.fn.selectedToSentence = () ->
  arr = []
  $('this :selected').each (i, sel) ->
    arr[i] = $(sel).html()
  arr.join(", ")
```

but it never returns the string.

-- edit --

I am calling it like:
    $('select[id$="_bar_ids"]').selectedToSentence()

-- /edit --

-- edit 2 --

at the CoffeeScript site, it shows the above script as compiling to:

```
var $;
$ = jQuery;
$.fn.selectedToSentence = function() {
  var arr;
  arr = [];
  $('this :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
    return arr[i] = $(selected).text();
  });
  return arr.join(", ");
};
```

-- /edit 2 --

I have also tried the following syntaxes:

```
$(@ :selected).each ...
$('@ :selected').each ...
$("#{@} :selected").each ...
```

all without success.

I've Googled, and looked around SO, perhaps with the wrong search terms, because I'm coming up empty.
I feel like it's just a syntactical thing.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a CoffeeScript issue, it's just a plain old jQuery issue. In particular "`'this :selected'`" isn't a valid selector in CSS or jQuery (`this` is a variable in JavaScript but it's meaningless in a selector string). If you want to use a CSS selector only on children of a certain element (like `this`, in your scenario) you can pass that element as the second parameter to `$`, e.g.:

```js
$(':selected', this).each ...
```